# How to set a window minimum size according to its content in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

To statically set a window minimum size to a `100x100` pixels frame in JavaFX 2.2 one would use:

```
stage.setMinWidth(100);
stage.setMinHeight(100);
```

Supposing we don't want to set a fixed minimum size, but we want the window to be resized to a minimum size that all its content (buttons, text fields, etc.) is still fully visible. How would we do that?

Comment: It is handled automatically by javafx internally !

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use stage.minWidthProperty().bind(... Binding expression here...);

The difficulty of course is to define the binding expression... it should depend on all your components but still it should work.

Resizing children will modify the binding expression and will change the minWidthProperty on your Stage.

Comment: This is not just a great solution based on that it is very simple from coding perspective (at least the basics are simple, the rest is just a fun challenge!), but it also looks great visually - No annoying glitches or lags. Simply great! +1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read the javadoc of `Pane`, `Region` and maybe `Group` nodes. On how they layout and resize their children. Basically if you don't set the preferred size of the pane then, by default, it will be calculated according to its content. Also have a look on [Window.sizeToScene()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene%28%29) method.